# Simple Flickr json data retriever not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, flickr

I have the following simple piece of code which retrieves data from Flickr in order to populate the empty "ul" element.
For some reason the returned "data" variable in "MyFeed.prototype.getFeed" is undefined. It should have the Json retrieved with the Flickr call. 
I don't understand why this happens.

I'm not allowed to change anything apart from adding stuff in the getFeed function.

Could you please share some thoughts about it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="data">

    </ul>

    <script>

        var MyFeed = function() {

        }

        var f = new MyFeed();

        MyFeed.prototype.setFeedUrl = function(url)
        {
            this.feedUrl = url;
            return this;
        }

        MyFeed.prototype.getFeed = function(data)
        {
            // I retrieve and inject in HTML the Flickr data from here...


        }

        f.setFeedUrl("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback={callback}&tags=london&tagmode=any&format=json").getFeed();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in getFeed, and even if you did `return data` as your question suggests, you are calling getFeed with no arguments, therefore data would be undefined

Comment: you've shown **no code** for `getFeed` - how do you expect anyone other than a psychic to be able to tell you what is wrong with your `getFeed` function

Comment: That's a template that I got as it is. I'm supposed to fill out that function with some code to retrieve the json and show it. The issue is that I don't know how to retrieve the JSON in the getFeed function. That's why it is empty. No psychic involved :)

Comment: ahhh - I thought `It should have the Json retrieved with the Flickr call` implied that you simply haven't shown the code here ... the problem is, you want someone to write all the code for you

Comment: No no don't get me wrong. I know how to write the code but I can't understand how to access the json using this template! Do you know what I mean? I know how to loop through the json response etc etc..

Comment: ps: here is the fiddle with the code I came up with --> http://jsfiddle.net/beppe0/dw2wtksf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `f` after the edit to the `prototype`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="data">

    </ul>

    <script>

        var MyFeed = function() {

        }

        MyFeed.prototype.setFeedUrl = function(url)
        {
            this.feedUrl = url;
            return this;
        }

        MyFeed.prototype.getFeed = function(data)
        {
            // I retrieve and inject in HTML the Flickr data from here...


        }

        var f = new MyFeed();

        f.setFeedUrl("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback={callback}&tags=london&tagmode=any&format=json").getFeed();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand the meaning of putting it afterwards. I've tried and it still undefined anyway. Can you please explain?

Comment: the order is unimportant - you can add to MyFeed.prototype at any time, and any MyFeed objects will `gain` that function

Comment: @JaromandaX  the issue here is that from the "getFeed" method I don't know how to retrieve the JSON as the "data" attribute is undefined. How can I access that data?

Comment: @JaromandaX ...as I specified above, the only thing i'm allowed to change is inside the "getFeed" method in which i need to retrieve the json from the Flickr URL and inject the data in the DOM. I cannot change/touch anything else. Could you help?